# Minimize the output of Tensorflow regression model using one of the inputs

Tags: tensorflow, keras, regression

I am trying to train a Tensorflow model using [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/regression#make_predictions) guide with the purpose of solving an optimization problem using deep neural networks (Tensorflow). The model I have so far takes 9 inputs and produces 1 output.

What I'm trying to do now is to use it in an application in which the goal is to **minimize the output value by adjusting one input value, given the other input values being fixed.**

For example, let's denote the input values `x1, x2, ..., x10` and the output `y`. Given the values for `x2, x3, ..., x10`, what is the value of `x1` that minimizes the output `y`? See the image below for a visual description of my problem.

[image: Problem description]

I have trained a network using Keras and saved it as `variable.data-00000-of-00001` and `variables.index` files, and loaded it using `tf.keras.models.load_model`.

The current code I have is an ultra-slow "hardcoded" optimization function that relies on appending values to lists by iterating over x1 values and running them through the network, append every output to the list, and observe which x1 value produced the lowest output. This is obviously not a very good solution. See code below.

```
for index, row in input_df.iterrows():
    prediction = model.predict(row[['x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4', 'x5', 'x6', 'x7', 'x8', 'x9']]).flatten()
    prediction = float(prediction)
    X1_predictions.ayend(prediction)

    # Optimized x1
    x1_values = []
    y_pred_values = []
    for x1 in np.arange(-1, 0, 0.01):
        row['x1'] = x1
        x1_values.append(x1)
        y_prediction = y_model.predict(row[['x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4', 'x5', 'x6', 'x7', 'x8', 'x9']]).flatten()
        y_prediction = float(y_prediction)
        y_pred_values.ayend(y_prediction)

    min_y_val = min(y_pred_values)
    min_y_idx = y_pred_values.index(min(y_pred_values))
    opt_x1 = x1_values[min_y_idx]

    x1_opt_list.ayend(opt_x1)
    y_opt_predictions.ayend(min_y_val)
```

I haven't worked with TF regression models like this before, how should I go about solving this in a more elegant matter using Tensorflow/Keras and not lists and for-loops?

Comment: You (probably) don't need a neural network for that task. If I was at your place, I would look at [scipy.optimize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html) or similar. It is completely possible to write that optimization problem with TensorFlow though, but I am not sure I see the point.

Comment: @Lescurel Well, the dataset consists of about 4000 data points, and they don't correlate that much. I've successfully trained a neural net to predict the output pretty well, so I would ideally stick with this solution.

Comment: If you have more details, I encourage you to add them in the question. Is your objective to "freeze" the current net and to modify the input based on the output of the net?

Comment: @Lescurel, Yes that is currently my strategy. However, I haven't worked on such an optimization problem before (I haven't really used DL models in production, only trained the for academic purposes), so I'm open to other suggestions. Lets say i can adjust x1 between 0-1. The thought is to find the x1 value that produces the lowest output value, based on the other 8 parameters being fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I can give you a rough example on how to solve an optimization problem with tensorflow.

Let's imagine that you have a certain function, and want to optimize the input to that function based on some ground truth y. Let's call that function `my_funct`. (In your case, it would be a frozen neural network). In my example, I will take a simple function, like a sum :

```
@tf.function
def my_funct(inp):
    return tf.reduce_sum(inp)
```

Now, lets define an input, and a ground truth. In that optimization problem, my ground truth in the sum of the input + 1. So at the end of the optimization my variable `x1` should be equal to `x1 +1`

```
inp = tf.random.normal((9,))
y_true = tf.reduce_sum(inp) + 1
```

Now, you need to encode the values that you want to optimize (in your example `x1`), in a `tf.Variable`. This is the way TensorFlow keep tracks of states that needs to be optimized. In our case, x1 is the first value of our input.

```
x1 = tf.Variable(inp[0])
```

Lets start the optimization in itself. We need:

- a cost function, that will tell us how far we are from the objective
- a optimizer, an algorithm that will modify the states of our program so we reduce our cost function.

In that case, I'm going to use the gradient descent optimizer and the mean squared error as an objective function, but there is plenty other possibilities that might fit your problem better.

```
opt = tf.optimizers.SGD()
cost = tf.losses.mse
```

Then, we can write the optimization in itself using TensorFlow. To do that, we need to calculate the gradient of our cost function in respect to our states, that we will give to the optimizer so it can modify the states in the right direction in order to minimize our cost.

This can be done that way:

```
STEPS = 200
for _ in range(STEPS):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        tape.watch(x1)
        y_pred = my_funct(tf.concat([[x1], inp[1:]], axis=0))
        loss = cost([y], [y_pred])
    grad = tape.gradient(loss, [x1])
    opt.apply_gradients(zip(grad, [x1]))
```

*It is a bit cumbersome to handle the `tf.Variable` with the rest of the input as I do with `tf.concat`. There might be a more elegant way of doing it, but I don't want to over engineer that simple example.*

At the end of that process, we should have something close to `x1=inp[0] + 1`
Let's check :

```
>>> inp[0] + 1
<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=2.5110626>
>>> x1
<tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=() dtype=float32, numpy=2.4934747>
```

Not so bad!

***Note:*** *As always in those problem, there is some hyper parameters that you can tune to get a faster, better results, such as the number of steps, the learning rate, etc.*

Comment: Thank you so much for this detailed and well-written response! I will try to implement this asap and I will give you a response as to how it went.

Comment: In your example, you have a ground truth which is `x1+1`, but in my case I want to minimize the output variable, `y`, of the DNN model without knowing the ground truth so to speak.  I'm not quite sure how to translate your example to my case since this is a ket difference?

Comment: If you want to minimize `y`, then your ground truth is probably `0`. (if the output of your DNN is positive).

Comment: That makes sense! I've implemented this now and it seems like it's working. However, the optimized result gives an infeasible result from a practical point of view. How would you limit `x1` to a certain range with this technique?

Comment: Then you need to add constraints. One way to go is to add a penalty to the cost function if the value of `x1` goes beyond/under a certain threshold.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far. It's now returning feasible values. However, it doesn't seem to find the optimal (or close to optimal) solution that minimizes the output. I've tried different optimizers from [TF's optimizers](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers) with different configurations of learning rates etc. I can see that the solution is not optimal because I run both the original `x1` and the optimized `x1` through my model, and the optimized one doesn't result in a lower output from the network.

Comment: I am, however, able to manually find an "optimized" `x1` value that reduces the output. It seems like the result from the optimizer often returns close to the exact value of what `x1` was originally for some reason..